# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, any fixes?

Tags: html

Every time I load the HTML file (whether it be on a server or simply localhost), I get the error message 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. My code is below.

```js
$('.flowers-wrap, .continents-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]','change', function () {
     var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
      $checked = $('input:checked'); 
     if ($checked.length) {       
                        var selector = '';
                        $($checked).each(function(index, element){
       if(selector === '') {
        selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                  
       } else {
        selector += ",[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";
       }
                        });                        
      $lis.hide(); 
                        console.log(selector);
      $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();      
     } else {
      $lis.show();
     }
    });
```

```css
body { font-family:'Arial'; color:#646464; }  
 .continents-wrap { float:left; width:20%; margin:0 5% 0 0; padding:0; }  
 .flowers-wrap { float:left; width:20%; margin:0 5% 0 0; padding:0; position:relative; } 
 .flowers { float:left; width:50%; }
 .flowers div { float:left; width:90%; height:68px; line-height:68px; padding:0 5%; background:#eee; margin:0 0 1px; position:relative; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="checkbox.js"></script>  
 
</head>

<body>


<div class="flowers-wrap">
            
                <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Flowers</h3>
                <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
                <form>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="red" /> Red</label><br>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="yellow" /> Yellow</label><br> 
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="pink" /> Pink</label><br>                     
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="purple" /> Purple</label><br>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="green" /> Green</label><br>  
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="other" /> Other</label>
                </form>
                <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong></p>
                <form>
                 <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="tiny" /> Tiny</label><br>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="small" /> Small</label><br>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="medium" /> Medium</label><br>                  
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="large" /> Large</label><br>
                    <label style="font-size:12px;"><input type="checkbox" id="giant" /> Giant</label>
                </form>                
                                            
           </div>
            
            <div class="continents-wrap">
            
                <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Continents</h3>
                
                <div class="continents" style="font-size:12px;">
                 <div>Africa <input type="checkbox" id="africa" /></div>
                    <div>Europe <input type="checkbox" id="europe" /></div>
                    <div>Asia <input type="checkbox" id="asia" /></div>
                    <div>North America <input type="checkbox" id="north-america" /></div>
                    <div>South America <input type="checkbox" id="south-america" /></div>
                    <div>Antarctica <input type="checkbox" id="antarctica" /></div>    
                    <div>Australasia <input type="checkbox" id="australasia" /></div>               
                </div>                
                
           </div>
            
            <div class="flowers">
             <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
             <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
             <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
          <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div> 
                <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div> 
                <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div> 
                <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>  
                <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>                  
         </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you include jquery? Doesn't look like it from the html

Comment: Please include jquery in your file because it is being used in your code.

Comment: And include it before your js file.

Answer (score 1):

Include the jquery library and it should be defined before the `checkbox.js`

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Comment: This has got rid of the error message now! Thanks!